# Browser not showing fonts properly

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, hebrew

I am trying to reach this site:
http:// www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON

When trying to get it using firefox or chrome on Windows it looks ok:

[image: picture of windows chrome]

But when I try getting it from firefox or chrome on Ubuntu all the Hebrew is showen incorrectly. It replaces them with characters like "×™×¡ ×¤×œ×× ×˜ - ××™×œ×•×Ÿ":

[image: picture of ubuntu firefox]

I checked on windows and the font seems to be monospace, which is standart.
However, I did installed `msttcorefonts` which didn't help either.

I there a way to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's displayed with the wrong encoding. To fix it in Firefox:

*View -> Text Encoding -> Unicode*

(Your issue has nothing to do with fonts.)